# How to create generic/reusable code with Scrum?

Tags: scrum, code-reuse

Scrum development is based on listing *user stories* and implementing them in during sprints. That approach - focusing on actual goals of the end product - definitely has its virtues, but what bugs me is that it doesn't advocate creating any generic/reusable code in the process, and actually I feel like it advocates *hacking*. For example, if an user story says

> Must be able to plot x versus y, and fit a line there.

my first thought is that, "hey, I need to create a generic graphing framework so that I can handle similar cases more efficiently later on". But that's not the goal in the scrum sprint; the goal is simply what the user story says.

So it is more desirable (from Scrum viewpoint) to simply hack something together so that the user story gets  implemented, instead of trying to understand the big picture and creating something more generic (which, of course, takes more time initially).

Is this unavoidable? Have I misunderstood something? How do you combine Scrum'ing an actual product with creating something reusable at the same time? Is reusability old-fashioned and overrated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if you create generic solution without actual need for it you are not following agile approach. You should avoid refactoring in advance. Otherwise it is gold plating where you are adding functionality which is not needed and which is not required by your customer at the moment (priority approach).

But sometimes it can be needed to create reusable component. This usually happens when more than one team plans to use the same component or when custom framework is created separately. In SCRUM you can do this in following approach. The main project which will use the component will become product owner for the component. It will define features which are needed as user stories. Component team will implement those features and provide the component to the main team in the iterative way.

So suppose that you have two projects which expects that they will need component for credit card payments. These two teams collect user stories with priorities and provides them to component team. They will plan together delivery so that component team provides only functionality needed by main teams in current sprint.

Comment: Whoa, I've never thought that a *project* could be a product owner. That's ingenious! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would only spend the time building a generic graphing framework when you need to, for the first sprint write something that plots X versus Y.  That might be as far as you go with graphing so there would be no need to write a framework.

If in further sprints you need to do more graphing, then create your framework.  Work in time to the sprint to allow you to do this.

Comment: But, if in further sprints I need to do more graphing, then the total time spent is "plot something (first sprint)" + "create plotting framework (second sprint)" + "maybe convert the first sprint's plot hack to use the more sophisticated mechanism of the second sprint, in order to be consistent". So in that case it would have been *less* work to build the framework in the first place. Obviously no methodology replaces being aware of the  big picture :-)

Comment: Don't write a 'hack' in the first instance, write it in such a way that you could make it generic without too much effort.
You also have to be aware that you could go to the effort of writing a framework in the first sprint and the client changes their mind...

Answer (score 2):

As Fermin says, the first time you need something isn't the time to start building a framework. YAGNI: you just build something that plots X vs Y.

Going further, I have found that even the second time you need something, it's *still* not time to build a framework yet. The problem with frameworks built on one or two use cases is that it's rare they'll actually be useful and generic enough for anything more than those one or two use-cases.

Building general, reusable, code is *hard*. There is nothing more useless and confusing to another developer coming after you than something that *appears* to be a framework, but is actually only used by one or two projects and is in fact tightly coupled with those projects.

One of the founding principles of the X Windows System was:

*The only thing worse than generalizing from one example is generalizing from no examples at all.*

Good advice I'd say!

Comment: +1, especially for "There is nothing more useless and confusing to another developer coming after you than something that appears to be a framework, but is actually only used by one or two projects and is in fact tightly coupled with those projects." Been there, done that...

Answer (score 1):

I think the issues of reusability and code quality lie outside of the team process dimension. Well maybe not entirely, but at least the agile approach does not deal with those. You're free to put in some extra effort to increase the reusability ratio or just quickly hack things together.

You could add some extra fixed time to each sprint to be used explicitly for code review and working on reusability.

Comment: I disagree on the note about code quality.  Most agilists advocate worrying about code quality, as failure there is one of the things that slows a team down.  It might be that only XP spells it out explicitly, but it's definitely critical to the process working.